# Is it possible to join Gmail with Google Apps?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I have my own domain and I'm pretty happy with using Google Apps on it. But, a lot of sites like [Google Code](http://code.google.com/) and others need a Gmail account.

Is it possible to merge a Gmail account with a Google Apps account?

Also, since quick logins on various web pages don't support Google Apps, merging/linking them would be really handy.

Comment: If you've got your own domain, you can either redirect your domain email to a gmail account OR set up a mail server with google for your domain.

Comment: if i'll redirect google-apps mail to gmail, then I can't answer emails with my domain =) I just read somewhere that merging is possible in google apps or it was planned to do or something like this...

Comment: Actually you can. I set up my account so that when I create a new message, I can choose from which email I'm sending from. It's easy because it brings everything in one inbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a Google product which doesn't take Google Apps for your Domain accounts, then you're currently out-of-luck. You're waiting on Google to support that.

You can create a gmail account and forward the mail to your normal address. Make sure the secondary email address (the password-reset one) is pointed to a place you actually read and trust. The set up forwarding, inside Gmail. Then you can continue reading email in the one place and have an account to use for those products that specifically require a Gmail-account.

Answer (score 0):

Just register for gmail account, set it to forward all messages to your main account, and stash the password away somewhere safe.